# Why do only two of these three addKeyCommand 's work

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, shortcut

I have three keyboard shortcuts I am trying add to my iPad program. Here are the three

```
        // add the "change Status" keyboard shortcut
    let statusShortcut = UIKeyCommand(input: "s", modifierFlags: UIKeyModifierFlags.Command, action: "changeStatusPressed:", discoverabilityTitle: "Change Status of Meeting")
    addKeyCommand(statusShortcut)

    // add the "add user" keyboard shortcut
    let addShortcut = UIKeyCommand(input: "+", modifierFlags: UIKeyModifierFlags.Command, action: "addButtonPressed:", discoverabilityTitle: "Add Participant to Meeting")
    addKeyCommand(addShortcut)

    // add the "remove user" keyboard shortcut
    let removeShortcut = UIKeyCommand(input: "-", modifierFlags: UIKeyModifierFlags.Command, action: "removeButtonPressed:", discoverabilityTitle: "Remove Participant to Meeting")
    addKeyCommand(removeShortcut)
```

only the second two are recognized and show up in the screen overlay when I press the Command key on the keyboard.  Also, only the second two work.

All there's actions are defined correctly.  Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure that there is no sequencing issue, I have changed the sequence of the above three and I still only see the + and - key modifiers.

Comment: I gave a very late answer, I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I am relatively new to this, but I think you are doing this wrong. Instead of what you're doing, do this.

Do all this after (outside) your ViewDidLoad:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
return true
}

override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    return [

UIKeyCommand(input: "S", modifierFlags: .Command, action: "changeStatusPressed:", discoverabilityTitle: "Change Status of Meeting"),
UIKeyCommand(input: "+", modifierFlags: .Command, action: "addButtonPressed:", discoverabilityTitle: "Add Participant to Meeting"),
UIKeyCommand(input: "-", modifierFlags: .Command, action: "removeButtonPressed:", discoverabilityTitle: "Remove Participant from Meeting"),

   ]
}

func changeStatusPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("command-s selected")
    // code for changeStatusPressed
}

func addButtonPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("command+ selected")
    // code for addButtonPressed
}

func removeButtonPressed(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("command- selected")
    // code for removeButtonPressed
}
```

Your issue could have been anywhere from improper capitalization in your function, or syntax, or something completely different! I hope this helps you (sorry it's so late).

Comment: Thanks Didn't realize it shouldn't be in ViewDidLoad